# How did the TARDIS blow up at the every point of the universe?

Tags: doctor-who

In "The Big Bang" episode the TARDIS was blowing up at the every point of the universe and because of that reason the Doctor could throw Pandorica into the TARDIS and recreates the universe. What does it mean to explode at "every point in the universe"? The TARDIS blew up but why at the every point of universe?

Answer (score 2):

The Tardis explosion caused a shock wave in time that led to a "total event collapse" in "The Pandorica Opens".  I think you just have to accept that whatever makes a TARDIS work was sufficiently powerful to destroy space-time if it exploded in such a manner.

To the question "what does this mean". This manifested itself as every star in the universe exploding - presumably in a manner that this would appear simultaneous at Earth if the special effect is taken literally.  That is - a star 4 light years away exploded 4 years in the past and a star ten years away ten years in the past - such that the whole universe goes dark at the same origin moment.
(Note in *Doctor Who* time can be rewritten in an instant - so those explosions in the past didn't exist until they were caused by the TARDIS.)

However this event also spread cracks in space-time prior to the explosion which was the main plot of Matt Smith Doctor 11's first season.  He was dealing with cracks before the event that caused them happened. In fact the efforts to assassinate the Doctor to prevent the cracks - one of which was blowing up the TARDIS - paradoxically caused them to happen in the first place!

Ultimately the solution was to reboot the universe using the pattern of the old universe.  Thus resulting in a crack free universe and Amy's parent's existing again.  The memories of the season -  which really never happened - as a forked branch in time - gets overlaid onto the memories of the participants like Rory and they proceed to new adventures.  Meanwhile the Silence proceed to plan a new way to deal with the Paradox of the Doctor on Trenzalore.

The transcript of the [“Pandorica Opens” from
Chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/31-12.htm):

> [Pandorica chamber]
>
> (River tries frantically to escape the Tardis as the Doctor is dragged closer and closer to the Pandorica, then fastened into the seat inside it. His arms, torso and head are clamped in place and all his old enemies stare at him.)
>
> DOCTOR: You lot, working together. An alliance. How is that possible?
>
> WHITE: The cracks in the skin of the universe.
>
> STARK: All reality is threatened.
>
> CYBERLEADER: All universes will be deleted.
>
> DOCTOR: What? And you've come to me for help?
>
> STARK: No. We will save the universe from you!
>
> DOCTOR: From me?
>
> CYBERLEADER: All projections correlate. All evidence concurs. The Doctor will destroy the universe.
>
> DOCTOR: No, no, no. You've got it wrong.
>
> CYBERLEADER: The Pandorica was constructed to ensure the safety of the Alliance.
>
> WHITE: A scenario was devised from the memories of your companion.
>
> STARK: A trap the Doctor could not resist.
>
> WHITE: The cracks in time are the work of the Doctor. It is confirmed.
>
> DOCTOR: No. no, no, not me, the Tardis. And I'm not in the Tardis, am I?
>
> WHITE: Only the Doctor can pilot the Tardis.
>
> DOCTOR: Please, listen to me!
>
> WHITE: You will be prevented.
>
> DOCTOR: Total event collapse! Every sun will supernova at every moment in history. The whole universe will never have existed. Please, listen to me!
>
> CYBERLEADER: Seal the Pandorica.
>
> DOCTOR: No! Please, listen to me! The Tardis is exploding right now and I'm the only one who can stop it! Listen to me!
> (The Pandorica closes.)
>
> [Tardis]
>
> (River opens the Tardis doors to discover she is parked right up against a rock wall.)
>
> RIVER: I'm sorry, my love.
>
> (The Tardis explodes. As Rory weeps over Amy's body, every star in the universe goes KaBOOM.)

Comment: In the future please mark quotes as such (I.e. a > at the start of each paragraph) and also make them readable with line breaks. Previously that quote was just one long paragraph of mess and wasn’t really legible.

Answer (score 1):

The TARDIS is infinite space and time pressed into a police box, at a single time.  When you take infinite space and time and cause it to explode outward, that shatters the fabric of reality at every point in space and time.

Comment: Could you give more detail about "TARDIS is infinite space and time"

Comment: @NastasyaFilippovna As confirmed in _Journey to the Center of the TARDIS_, the core of the TARDIS consists of a star at the point of collapse, emitting infinite energy for that exact moment.  Thus, the TARDIS has infinite power and can use that to create infinite space inside.

Comment: A short answer woul d be that real physics and cosmology often seems very weird, nonsenical, and paradoxical to most of us.  And Dr. Who physics is many times weirder and doesn't make sense to physicists and scientists.

Comment: @M.A.Golding [Nobody ever said we're about real-world science](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7364/141465)... ;)